# Don't allow webView to play sound on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am developing an iOS app built in Swift with two webViews using WKWebView. One of the web has a default sound that sounds every time the webView loads (the web is not mine). So I need to stop or don't allow the webView to reproduce any sound. There is any method to get this? I tried some code but it doesn't work. I'm using xCode 9 and Swift 4.

This is the code I've tried (but it doesn't work):

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)  
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)  
}
```

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "theWeb")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Thank you for your responses and sorry for my question, I'm new to programming.

Comment: Welcome, and good question. Do you know how the page plays the sound? Does it have a JavaScript onLoad handler, or something else? Is the sound a media file or HTML5 WebAudio or something else? You're likely going to have to either reconfigure the WKWebView or inject some JavaScript, but it depends on how the page makes the sound.

Comment: Thank you for your response @RobNapier This is the web: https://danfg95glucose.azurewebsites.net If you open the web, you have to press the sound button (right top corner) and this is ok, but if the big number is above 160 or below 70 it stars to sound like an alarm. This is the sound I want to avoid but I don't know if it is media file or HTML5 WebAudio. Thank you for your response. I started programming very recently and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm looking for a way to mute/unmute all sound from any random website visited via WKWebView. Because of this I wouldn't know how the page plays sound. I'm not familiar with Javascript. Are there any scripts that would handle all cases that would give the ability to mute/unmute the most common cases? For example youtube/vimeo/soundcloud would be common and might all play sound differently but someone who built their own site with an unconventional way of playing sound would be uncommon. The scripts would handle the former but not the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in question are these:

```
<audio src="audio/alarm.mp3" preload="auto" loop="true" class="alarm mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio/alarm2.mp3" preload="auto" loop="true" class="urgent alarm2 mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

The first thing I would try is changing the `WKWebViewConfiguration`. In order to do that, you have to create the `WKWebView` programmatically and insert it into your view. You can't do this with Interface Builder unfortunately. Here's some untested code that may work. (If it doesn't we can dig into this further, but this is where I'd start. The next step if this doesn't work is to implement a `WKNaviagtionDelegate` to deny the audio load requests.)

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.mediaTypesRequiringActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeAll

webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
view.addSubview(webView)
```

If your web view doesn't fill the entire view, then a convenient way I've found to make this work is to add a blank `UIView` in Interface Builder and lay it out where you want it. Then just put the webView in that blank view at runtime (and make it the same size). This is nice because it lets you do all the layout in IB, but still insert the web view where needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helps me a lot. But finally I change the `WKAudiovisualMediaTypesAll` (it doesn't works on swift 4), to `.audio`.